# Conquering the Universe

Tags: cipher, pattern, number-sequence

Can you decipher the numbers and determine who I am?

`24083272403040832724032608240304120727327240824071232724082308`

This is my first puzzle and I have no idea how hard this is going to be, but I'd love some feedback

Hint 1:

> Groups of twos and threes are key

Hint 2:

> I'm not your standard person, I'm a little quirky

Hint 3: (Warning this is a major spoiler)

> Rows, Cols

Hint 4: (Since no one has figured it out, this is the biggest hint by far)

> Keyboards are laid out like a grid

Comment: Typically puzzles like this with just a string of numbers and no hints or clues are poorly received on PSE. If you truly think this will be solvable without any hints, you can leave it as-is, but you'll likely get more positive feedback if you at least point us in the right direction!

Comment: This puzzle is not a good example of a question we'd like to see on this site. For more information please see this meta question: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do So I, voted to close as Too Broad (surprised nobody else did)

Comment: @BaileyM I added a hint. I hope that helps point everyone in the right direction. I think it's solvable from there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> Dr. John Faust from V for Vendetta

Using the list from @AlirezaTabatabaeian and the last clue

> Each row of letters on your keyboard is numbered 0-3 and each column is numbered starting at 1. Taking each number pair as a Row/Column and 327 being a space as it is in the 3rd row and extends from col 2 to col 7 (from @BaileyM) gives you "Vi Veri Veniversum Vivus Vici" - a quote attributed to Dr. John Faust in the movie V for Vendetta.

Comment: Spaces are '327' because they're in the 3rd row and extend from col 2 to col 7. :P

Comment: This same message could also lead to Aleister Crowley.

Comment: @Geobits I did not know that phrase was in his writings, but Lampost42 was correct in his answer. Since that phrase pulls up V for Vendetta first it seems like an easy jump

Comment: I'm glad someone finally got this even though I basically gave it away in the hints

Comment: Right, I'm not saying he's wrong at all, just that the phrase doesn't necessarily lead to a *single* person, so I'd count either as right. For the record, Googling that phrase brings up [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi_veri_universum_vivus_vici) as the first result for me, where it shows both sources.

Comment: @Geobits That's the same page for me. I went with the most obvious person. I was on a V for Vendetta kick when I made this which is the main reason lol

Comment: I thought it would've been solved a lot sooner. The keyboard used as a grid came from a slightly simpler puzzle I had seen which was solved pretty quickly from what I remember

Answer (score 6):

24 08 327

24 03 04 08 327

24 03 26 08

24 03 04 12 07 27 327

24 08 24 07 12 327

24 08 23 08

looks like a patern all lines starts with 24 and end up to 327 or 08

Comment: This is actually pretty good. Each of your lines could be a word, with each group of digits corresponding to a letter.

Comment: @randal'thor is on the right track

Comment: @randal'thor I wouldn't put each set on a different line

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Answer

Since the hint says that "groups of twos and threes" are relevant, I hunted through the list to find some. `2408` and `327` show up multiple times. Splitting the string up such that `24`, `08`, and `327` are all pulled out by themselves, we get:

```
24 08 327 24 0304 08 327 24 0326 08 24 0304120727 327 24 08 24 0712 327 24 08 2308
```

If we then split the `0#` strings up as sets of twos, we get the resulting string:

```
24 08 327 24 03 04 08 327 24 03 26 08 24 03 04 12 07 27 327 24 08 24 07 12 327 24 08 23 08
```

This doesn't appear to be ascii or alphabetical characters, since neither really fit the pattern. I'm a bit concerned with the `07 27 327` since that's the only location that `27` shows up exclusively from `327`. From this point, I'm not sure where to go, but it's a start, at least.

Comment: Not a lot of progress, but maybe looking at the split characters will give someone else inspiration to solve the rest.

Comment: you are on the right track but you've missed part of the hint